# How to find the redundant representation of Finite field in GF(2^8)

Tags: finite-fields

Iam interested to understand the concept of redundant representation in finite field GF(2^8).

How to calculate the basis change matrix from redundant to polynomial/normal representation  in $GF(2^8)$ for irreducible polynomial $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ ?
in this [reference](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-44586-2_25.pdf), he smallest degree of redundancy for GF(2^8) is 17 , I can not get it from here.
I would greatly appreciate it to provide me with a numerical example.

Comment: I guess that polynomial/normal representations in this context refer to the use of either a monomial basis or a normal basis of the field. But what does *redundant representation* mean? I like to think I know a few things about finite fields, but I don't recall ever hearing such  a term. Can you clarify the meaning? We cannot help if key parts of the question are kept secret.

Comment: Also, please check out [our abridged guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/11619) for pointers on improving questions.

Comment: redundant representation is used in cryptography (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-44586-2_25.pdf) and (https://tches.iacr.org/index.php/TCHES/article/view/884/835) , it has a good feature of permutation for squaring.